# Codeigniter Data Retrieve

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, search, join

Here is my database structure [image: database]

same subject may have many teachers. First database teacher field is foreign with another database. When searching individual subject how to get full teacher details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM subject
FULL OUTER JOIN teachers
ON subject.teacher = teachers.id
WHERE subject.subject LIKE '$search';
```

**Why FULL OUTER JOIN**??

[image: 01]

**How in CI?**

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM subject FULL OUTER JOIN teachers ON subject.teacher = teachers.id WHERE subject.subject LIKE '$search' ");
$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```

Comment: how to add individual search query

Comment: how you want search ??

Comment: If someone search for math then it will return all teachers details of math

Comment: @devpro you have get back the response ;)

Comment: U r my second friend after fred-ii in SO FAMILY

Comment: Yes I have checked .. :)